# ReactNative FlatList Pull-to-Refresh

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am using the `FlatList` component in React Native and wish to implement the pull to refresh functionality.

When adding the onRefresh callback, the style of the FlatView component appears to be overriden and no longer applies.

Was wondering whether anybody else had experienced this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I've had someone else I have work with experience this. I told him to scrap that pull to refresh and make a better one in 2 hours. The concept behind pull to refresh with react or react native IMO is not a good idea. Pull to refresh kind of defeats the purpose of state don't you think? Just have the  state update and the list update itself. 99 time out of a user wants the list to refresh on it's own.  Make it intuitive, put new entries on the bottom and highlight them or something like that. Give them a filter or order by options as well. Or let them turn on/off auto update on the list.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense how would using React Native make pull to refresh a bad idea? It's a UX choice. I have no idea what you mean by "defeats the purpose of state" either.

Comment: @NightStrider can you provide a reproduction of the issue on snack.expo.io  - providiing `onRefresh` causing the styles to change sounds like a bug, works well for me.

Comment: @jevakallio Sorry I should have explained why. My comment was too long so I just had the idea of stopping. State determines how our component renders and behaves and allows it to be dynamic. You can add a much much more elegant user experience with state than with a user asking to refresh.